# Getting MySql Error 'aio read' returned OS error 0

Tags: mysql-8.0, errors

MySql server goes down after running for couple of months. I can see below error in the MySQL error logs.

```
2024-02-12T14:15:58.414920Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2024-02-12T14:15:58.414998Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 5000
2024-02-12T14:15:59.501763Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-12T14:16:03.863497Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-12T14:16:04.532165Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-02-12T14:16:04.532865Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-02-12T14:16:04.709706Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-03-05T15:34:57.431340Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File .\database_name\table.ibd: 'aio read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
2024-03-05T15:34:57.441756Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2024-03-05T16:43:47.497114Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2024-03-05T16:43:47.497144Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 1468
2024-03-05T16:43:47.684108Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-03-05T16:43:51.477351Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-03-05T16:43:51.954649Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-03-05T16:43:51.955345Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-03-05T16:43:52.013034Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Any idea why this error is coming periodically?

Please help.

Comment: look for the mysql error file, which will tell you why it shut down, but usually it means that the drive is full

Comment: The error log is shared above. Forgot mention this is windows platform and we are using WAMP for MySQL.

Comment: post the error log here, it must have the error i it, wamp is not made for long time use, it is mire an developer tool

Comment: Below are the 2 error logs generated during the incident. @nbk FYI the drive is not full. 
2024-03-05T15:34:57.431340Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File .\database_name\table.ibd: 'aio read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
2024-03-05T15:34:57.441756Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.

Comment: if the operating system says it can not read the file, you can have a major problem, that your hard drive is defect, you can try to repaor it with system tools and also should look at the s.m.a.r.t information of the hard drive to check how many errors youn have accumulated

Comment: also post the complete error log, the surrounded lines help often to determine the error better. also also see in the event viewer to see if the system noticed more errors

Comment: @nbk  I have shared the surrounding lines as well in the question itself. I have noticed that every time the error is happening on the same idb file. Is this issue related to the table? The tables hold transactional data. One more thing, once I start the MySQL service the database starts and works.

I will check the server event viewer and share any errors.

Comment: you can try to repair the idb file, search  for it . I hope you have backups  for your databases. still check the hard drive, it will need to be replaced  i suspect